# Footer at the bottom, visible only when scrolling down past body element / past 100% of height of window?

Tags: html, css

I want the `body element` to be in focus when opening the website and the `footer element` to be on the bottom of the body. So the `footer element` has to be after the `body element`. I don't want them to overlap. I want to have to scroll down to reach `footer element`.

[image: expl.png]

```
<html>    
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "master.css">   
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id = "container">
        <div class = "top-container">
            <div id = "logo"><img url="logo.png" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class = "center-container">
            <div class = "title"><h1>Current Settings</h1></div>
            <div id = "center_text_box">
                <p>URL:</p> <p><span>%PLACEHOLDER_URL%</span></p>
                <p>URL Refresh Rate:</p><p><span>%PLACEHOLDER_URR%</span>(s)</p>
                <p>Brightness:</p> <p><span>%PLACEHOLDER_Brightness%</span>(&#37;)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "bottom-container">
                <div class = "title"><h1>Logs</h1></div>
                <div class = "text-box">%PLACEHOLDER_1%</div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class = "footer">
            <ul>
                <li><a href= "http://metrici.ro/"><img src="logo_icon.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a href= "https://www.facebook.com/metricirecognition/"><img src = "Facebook_icon.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href= "https://www.linkedin.com/company/metrici/"><img src = "LinkedIn_icon.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href= "https://www.youtube.com/user/MetriciLPR"><img src = "YouTube_icon.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id = "trademark">
                <span>2019 TradeMark</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}

body {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    background-color: rgba(20,20,20,0.3);
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.top-container, .bottom-container, .center-container, .dropwdown-container {
    position: absolute;
}

.top-container {
    left: 30%;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 40%;
}

.center-container {
    left: 20%;
    top: 10%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 250px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.bottom-container {
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 0; 
    height: 350px;
    width: 80%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}

.footer ul {
    flex: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer li {
    display: inline;
}
.footer img {
    width:5%;
}
```

`position:absolute` isn't the answer. Or at least I couldn't make what I wanted with it.
Right now the `footer` is overlapping `body` and `.bottom-container`.

Changing `#container` from `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` makes the sub-divs : `top-container`, `center-container`, `bottom-container` to move to the top of the window and be on top of each other.

Is this achievable without JavaScript or jQuery ?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have anything after the closing body element other than the closing html element. You have your footer in there at the moment

Comment: @j08691 Thank you for pointing that out. I did not notice that. Unfortunately, it didn't fix a thing.

Comment: On top of j08691 correct comment, just make #container min-height 100vh; `#container{ min-height:100vh; position:relative; }` and put the footer after the #container element in the DOM. Make sure to change it to relative position.

Comment: @KaiQing Added `min-height: 100vh;` to `#container` and nothing changed.

Comment: @KaiQing After I've added `min-height: 100vh;` to `#container` and changed `footer` from `position:absolute` to `position:relative` it worked as I wanted it to. Thank you !
Can you explain why does `min-height: 100vh` or `height: 100vh` work, but `min-height: 100%` and `height: 100%` do not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating from comments -

Making the footer position relative will allow it to be placed after the container element. Giving container a min-height of 100vh makes that container have a minimum of 100% of the window's rendered screen value, where as defining it as 100% won't because it knows not of the parent height. Weird one in CSS, I know.

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    min-height:100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.footer{
    position:relative;
}
```

These css changes would correct the display for container and footer.

As for the other position issues you are having - I would consider not using absolute positions on everything. By the looks of the content and the css, you could make basic use of floats, or grid, to achieve that layout. And using percentages as offsets always leave conflicts open as you scale the browser. I suggest making those actual values, like 4em, etc. Without knowing much more about the expectations of the display, I cannot really advise much more on that. Only that going position:absolute crazy can be very difficult to balance for all devices.